# Use Stored Procedure to "EXECUTE AS USER" and Apply to Calling Context (Session)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, impersonation

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Windows 7 box.  I have created a stored procedure to run the SQL command `EXECUTE AS USER`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ImpersonateUser
AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE AS USER = 'UserName';
END
```

Then, I'm trying to see if I am impersonating the user...

```
PRINT CURRENT_USER;

EXEC ImpersonateUser;

PRINT CURRENT_USER
```

...and the result is...

```
dbo
dbo
```

...when I want it to be...

```
dbo
UserName
```

This doesn't work, of course, because the `EXECUTE AS USER` statement is only valid inside the stored procedure `ImpersonateUser`.  **My question is this:** Is it possible for the stored procedure `ImpersonateUser` to affect the calling context (session)?  I want to encapsulate (and hide) other logic in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible. Any EXECUTE AS change is automatically reverted at the end of a procedure.

Other things that dont live past the scope of the procedure are changes using the SET command and #TempObjects.

However, what you could do is encapsulate the logic that needs to be executed under the different security context in a procedure and then call that from within the procedure that changes the context. Something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CallWithImpersonateUser
   @ProcedureName
AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE AS USER = 'UserName';
  EXEC @ProcedureName;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer by Sebastian is correct, but still you have to grant impersonate for calling user.
[Syntax can be found here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178640%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON LOGIN::[login_to_be_impersonated] to [login1];
GO
```